# Excel 2010 VBA Length of Column given column index

Tags: excel, vba

I am finding this surprisingly hard to find an answer for, given its simple description.  I hope this is not a duplicate, though it probably is because of its simplicity, and I simply cannot find the answer.

In VBA, I have hundreds of columns, and I'd like to know all their lengths.  I know there are exactly "COLS" columns.  I want something like this:

```
For i in COLS
   length = 'Some one line formula to find the length of column i
   'Some code that works with the value of length
Next i
```

By length I mean the number of non-empty cells... For my specific purposes there will be no blank cells in the columns, and all the cells in the column I wish to count will contain text (all the rest will be empty).

Help would be much appreciated on this seemingly simple matter!

Edit: I also want to make this dependent on the column index (which will be 'i' in the loop above).  I won't always know the column letter...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will count <s>text</s> non-empty cells in VBA:

```
For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i))
Next
```

Comment: Being a little pedantic in case others readers mis-interpret this - COUNTA counts non-empty cells (ie both text strings and numbers). In this particular case it will the same answer as the xlup methods given the data layout in the question (ie no blanks within the cell range)

Comment: That's perfect, Thanks very much to everyone who contributed.  I found it surprisingly difficult to find an answer to this question given it doesn't seem like an intuitively difficult concept.  I was aware how to do this for the column "A" in particular, but wasn't sure how I would extend this to an arbitrary column given its index.  This helped clear that up, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It is best to use a routine that works automatically from the last row in all Excel versions.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use

```
LastRowColA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

to find last used row in column A.
Navigating through every column you can have what you want...

Comment: 65536 is no longer the row limit in Excel: since 2007 we've had 1,000,000+ rows possible.

Comment: @JonEgerton: yes, I know. Anyway mine is just an example of what OP could do. Then he has to help himself, don't you think? Anyway, thanks for your correct suggestion!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last non-empty row using Range(large row number, column).End(xlUP).row where large row number should be large enough to always be beyond your last used cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative approach using the worksheet function CountA as follows

Test Data:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    A    A
     B    B
C    C    C
D    D    D
E         E
```

VBA function:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim length As Integer
    max = 0
    For i = 1 To 3
        'CountA returns the number of non-blank cells in a range
        length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht.Columns(i))
        If length > max Then max = length
    Next i

MsgBox max - 1 ('remove 1 if you have column headers)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len = sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' gives the count of B column
len = sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' gives the count of A column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim i as integer
For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    debug.print i, cells(i, rows.count).end(xlup).row
Next
```